# Webservice issue with the version Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common

Tags: biztalk, rollback, gac, biztalk-2016

We are migrating to a new Biztalk 2016 environment, and while performing tests in our QA environment I discovered our app admins installed a newer version of the Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll than exists on our Dev and Developer workstation environments. The upgraded developer Workstations and the Development environment are on 4.1.0.0, while the new QA instances are on 5.0.414.0. This causes an error when calling one of our webservices that doesn't happen in the lower environments. Here is the
error.

```
[A]Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ConfigurationSourceSection cannot be cast to [B]Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ConfigurationSourceSection. Type A originates from ''Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'' in the context ''Default'' at location ''C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common\5.0.414.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll''. Type B originates from ''Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'' in the context ''Default'' at location ''C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\radiantticket.mdm\d243f84e\660457a3\assembly\dl3\c57ec7c2\00590e12_5439cf01\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll''.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IRadiantTicketsMDMService.LoadTicketTypeData(AMCHO ticketTypeRequest)
   at RadiantTicketsMDMServiceClient.LoadTicketTypeData(AMCHO ticketTypeRequest)
```

Apparently the web services had a reference to the 5.0.505.0 version of that dll. I've attempted the several binding redirects similar to the one below to get the next error

```
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common" 
                      culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.505.0" newVersion="5.0.414.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
```

And the new error

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IRadiantTicketsMDMService.LoadTicketTypeData(AMCHO ticketTypeRequest)
   at RadiantTicketsMDMServiceClient.LoadTicketTypeData(AMCHO ticketTypeRequest)
```

Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common

Comment: So what version is in your Production environment?  Make your Dev or QAT environment match that, otherwise you might have issues when you go to Production.  If Prod has the later version, I would recommend upgrading your Dev, and recompiling.

Comment: The prod environment hasn't been setup yet. That and I do not know how to remove and reinstall the older Microsoft.Practices and have been having trouble identifying anything that explains how to do so.

Comment: Then I would snapshot dev, then upgrade the Microsoft Practices in dev, and see if you get the same issue.  You can then also debug and find out exactly where it is throwing the error and possibly also fix it.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, I will try taht.